# salt-call to execute a state file in python script

Tags: python, salt-stack

How to execute a salt-call to execute a state file on the minion from a python script?

For example, I would like to call the below state file in a python script

```
salt-call -c /etc/salt-praveen state.apply database.create
```

Answer (score 0):

You want Python's subprocess module:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess

subprocess.check_call(["salt-call", "-c", "/etc/salt-praveen", "state.apply", "database.create"])
```